# Who makes the puzzles hidden inside The 39 Clues books?

Tags: the-39-clues

In almost every single *The 39 Clues* book, there are puzzles hidden inside the book, such as on the page numbers, or on the covers. i.e, in *The Viper's Nest* (series 1, book 7), starting on page 39 there is Morse Code hidden on the page. And on the front cover, there is the string MDIALAE=RC, and on the back cover this is ARGLEDRGAE, which when stacked it says

```
MDIALAE=RC  
ARGLEDRGAE
```

MADRIGAL LEADER = GRACE.

**Who designs these puzzles?**

---

Little bit of random stuff:

You can solve these puzzles and type the answer in on the [The 39 Clues site](http://the39clues.com).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In-universe or out-of-universe?

Comment: @Shokhet - out of universe, they aren't in universe.

Comment: What are you asking for? Someone at Scholastic probably puts the puzzles together. Do you want a name? (I doubt the authors do it, but they might)

Comment: @Shokhet - yes, names.

Comment: @Shokhet - exactly, your last sentence there. Does a team at Scholastic do it? Does the author? Does the author find someone? Etc.